# List of [newfloat] – change font

Tags: fonts, table-of-contents, tocloft

Using the `tocloft` package, I can change the appearance of the "List of Tables/Figures" by redefining `\cfttoctitlefont` etc.

However, I created a new float type, called "Example", with the `newfloat` package.
Is there a way to control the fonts in the "List of Examples" similarly?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the `newfloat` package internally uses `\listoffigures` to build the new lists, it's enough to redefine `\cftloftitlefont`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{newfloat}

\renewcommand\cfttoctitlefont{\normalfont\itshape}
\renewcommand\cftloftitlefont{\normalfont\itshape}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment{example}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listofexamples

\end{document}
```

[image]